# How to check the daily number of downloads of each version when multiple versions of the app are uploaded in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

If we upload multiple versions of the app in Google Play, how can we check the daily downloads of each version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Google Playstore only maintains a single version.

eg. if you have an "XYZ" app with version 1 and hosted on google playstore. after few days you have update XYZ app with version 2. Google unpublish the version 1 and publishes the version 2

you can see you version vise downloads on google playstore developer console.

When you update an app then google playstore intimates the version 1 user about version 2 availability.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. we uploaded multiple versions of the app for multiple api levels of Android

Comment: how ? with different package and application name ? may i correct ?

Comment: you can specify the min and max api level from gradle and manifest

Comment: below API 8 devices with one version and above API 8 devices with another version of the app

Comment: with same app name and package name ?

Comment: then it will remove the earliest version with newer update